# Listing Expected Parameters for Fabric Tasks

Tags: python, fabric

I have looked at the documentation and haven't found this.  **fab -l** or **fab -d**  do not display the expected parameters.  I also played with***fab -l <task>*** and the like to see if there was some undocumented support for this.  Anyone know how or have suggestions?

Comment: As mentioned by JustB, this is now given in the output of `fab -d`.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't found any automated way. What I do is put it into the docstring as in:

```
@task
def sometask(parma='Foo'):
    """Does some common, tedious task.

    sometask:parma=Foo
    """
```

So when you execute `fab -d sometask` you get:

```
Displaying detailed information for task 'sometask':

    Does some common, tedious task.

        sometask:parma=Foo
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I thought but then I reminded myself "DRY". :-) I wonder if, with some clever Python magic, we could append the signature (or even better: a "per-task arg" transformation thereof, like in your example) to the docstring?

Comment: If you actually give a real example it's still DRY and you're writing docs.

Comment: I would agree if we were discussing giving a real example but we are not; we are just repeating the signature here which I'd much rather not have to specify and/or update.  There may be certain tasks that warrant examples and others that don't especially when you have to make pragmatic choices under tight timelines.  I will try implementing something to this effect after making time to increase my Python-fu.

Answer (score 2):

I have fabric version 1.8.2 and when I run `fab -d sometask` I get the following

```
⇒ fab -d build
Displaying detailed information for task 'build':

Build task description

Arguments: version='dev'
```

And I have not added anything about the arguments in the docstring. So I suppose that Fabric's dev have added that feature.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to work with any tasks that are decorated with anything other than the default decorators like @task.

```
fab -d hostName
Displaying detailed information for task 'hostName':

No docstring provided
Arguments: arg='test'
```

And this is the Fabric task.

```
@task
def hostName(arg='test'):
run("hostname -f")
```

I guess it's probably something to do with the bubbling up of arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work with a bit of fiddling. I am running 1.11.1. It appears to have a lot to do with the order of the decorators. For example, here are various combinations and the results of running `fab -d <task>` for these code blocks:

Here is works as expected with ***JUST*** the @task decorator:

```
@task
def setupDNS(search, nameserver, interface):
    '''
    Configure search and nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf
    '''

[mpetronic@mpws.ws fabric]$ fab -d setupDNS
Displaying detailed information for task 'setupDNS':

    Configure search and nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf

    Arguments: search, nameserver, interface
```

Add a @runs_once decorator **BELOW** @task and no args are shown:

```
@task
@runs_once
def setupDNS(search, nameserver, interface):
    '''
    Configure search and nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf
    '''

[mpetronic@mpws.ws fabric]$ fab -d setupDNS
Displaying detailed information for task 'setupDNS':

    Configure search and nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf

    Arguments:
```

Add a @runs_once decorator **ABOVE** @task and args are shown:

```
@runs_once
@task
def setupDNS(search, nameserver, interface):
    '''
    Configure search and nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf
    '''

[mpetronic@mpws.ws fabric]$ fab -d setupDNS
Displaying detailed information for task 'setupDNS':

    Configure search and nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf

    Arguments: search, nameserver, interface
```

Add a @parallel decorator **BELOW** @task and args are not shown (jut like @runs_once) however, trying to add @parallel **ABOVE** @task makes fabric think this is not even a task anymore. If you replace @parallel with @serial (above @task) it DOES show the args.

```
@parallel
@task
def setupDNS(search, nameserver, interface):
    '''
    Configure search and nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf
    '''

[mpetronic@mpws.ws fabric]$ fab -d setupDNS

Fatal error: Task 'setupDNS' does not appear to exist. Valid task names:
    addNode
    auditHost
```

But, there is a workaround for the @parallel decorator. You **MUST** provide an argument to the decorator. I just use the default of None so that, internally, no behavior changes occur during execution but fabric is happy and displays the args for me. You still do need to stack @parallel **ABOVE** @task.

```
@parallel(pool_size=None)
@task
def setupDNS(search, nameserver, interface):
    '''
    Configure search and nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf
    '''

[mpetronic@mpws.ws fabric]$ fab -d setupDNS

Displaying detailed information for task 'setupDNS':

    Configure search and nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf

    Arguments: search, nameserver, interface
```